# NetBeans, XAMPP, Dropbox, Chrome - Could not access the URL through the external browser

Tags: google-chrome, netbeans, xampp, external, dropbox

I'm a student learning web-developing. My IDE is NetBeans.

I'm having a problem concerning Chrome running NetBeans web-projects that are located in Dropbox. I have recently set my XAMPP htdocs location to my Dropbox for easy syncing through my desktop and laptop, and everything works fine with both IE and Firefox, but I get the `"Could not access the URL through the external browser. Check the browser configuration."` error if I try to run projects with Chrome.

The only modifications I have done to make Dropbox my "htdocs"-parent is editing the DocumentRoot and Directory properties (from: `"C:/xampp/htdocs"` to: `"C:/Dropbox/webdev/htdocs"`).

Is this a security feature in Chrome? Or am I missing something strange, as it works in both IE and Firefox?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!